# Asserting that a certain error occurs

Tags: python, testing, try-catch, throw, assertion

Given the following code:

```
def fun(param):
    if param == 'a':
        assert False
    else:
        return None

# fun('a') THIS THROWS AN AssertionError
# PSEUDOCODE FOR WHAT I WANT TO DO:
# assert (fun('a') throws an AssertionError)
assert fun('b') == None
```

How do I assert that the first function call (fun('a')) will give me an AssertionError? Will I need a try-catch for this or is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pytest`](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html#assertions-about-expected-exceptions) for this:

```
import pytest
...
with pytest.raises(AssertionError):
    fun('a')
```

This will raise an error if `fun('a')` *does not* raise an AssertionError.

Or, if you are using `unittest`, and you are within a `TestCase`, you can use [`assert
Raises`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises):

```
self.assertRaises(AssertionError, fun, 'a')
```

Also, as other answers have mentioned, you would be better off `raise`ing an error than asserting `False`. And if you do raise an error, you could raise one that tells the user more about what went wrong, or raise your own custom exception:

```
import pytest

class AError(Exception):
    pass

def fun(param):
    if param == 'a':
        raise AError("You passed 'a'; don't do that!")
    else:
        return None

with pytest.raises(AError):
    fun('a')
```

Comment: This answered my question perfectly fine. I could not reply instantly since I was busy. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Throwing assertions is likely a better approach. As an example:

```
def fun(param):
    if param == 'a':
        raise AssertionError('Param is equal to \'a\'.')
    else:
        return None

try:
    fun('b')
    print('Equalling \'b\' worked fine.')
    fun('a')
    print('This line is not printed...')
except AssertionError as err:
    print('An assertion error has been raised:')
    print(err)
```

gives:

```
Equalling 'b' worked fine.
An assertion error has been raised:
Param is equal to 'a'.
```